# File name with wildcard entry in C on linux

Tags: c, linux, filenames, wildcard

I want to read a file with wild cards in C which should run on Linux. 
I have files such as out*.txt files where * can be any 1/2 digits. I want to read all these files.

Comment: Find a regular expression library or get comfortable with `isdigit()`?

Comment: You could write your program to take a list of filenames as the command arguments, and let the shell do the wildcard expansion:  `myprog out*.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) function from glob.h

Comment: I am sorry, but I am new to this. So, not understanding how exactly to use this in my C program for my scenario.